# Security or Passport control needed in AMS if transiting from non Schengen to non Schengen?

Tags: schengen, transit, ams

Arriving from JFK into AMS Gate F, transiting to IST, Gate D

Will I need to do anything beyond just walking in to the gate?

I have a 50 minute tight connection.

I've looked at the map and I don't understand if I can travel freely between gate D54 and gate F8

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket? If they are, you definitely won't have passport control. I'm less sure about security though it's probably likely.

Comment: There used to be a security check but I don't think it's the case anymore. No reason to have a passport check and I don't see any on the map: https://assets.ctfassets.net/biom0eqyyi6b/1HpeRtxnyckeO8ae6guEEo/9c6387e79118006e37061c1ace5718af/Schiphol_Airport_Map_Departures.pdf The passport checks are marked on the map: see the red dotted line on the ground between concourse D and C.